# How to change length of arrow in commutative diagram

Tags: commutative-diagrams

I want to draw a commutative diagram, I drew it but it is too large to fit in a page, and i want to reduce the length of arrows. I Changed Column Sep value but no luck. Any idea How to do it?

````
    \begin{tikzcd}[row sep=1.5em, column sep = .000001em]
   &&
   Hom_H(P_n,A) \arrow[rr,"\alpha"] \arrow[dr,dashed, swap,"d_n"] \arrow[dd,swap] &&
    Hom_H(P_n,B)\arrow[dd] \arrow[dr,dashed,swap,"d_n"] \arrow[rr,"\beta"]&&
    Hom_H(P_n,C) \arrow[rr]\arrow[dr,dashed ,swap,"d_n "]\arrow[dd] &&0\\
    &0\arrow[rr] &&  Hom_H(P_{n+1},A) \arrow[rr,"\alpha",near start] \arrow[dd]&&
    Hom_H(P_{n+1},B) \arrow[dd]\arrow[rr,"\beta",near start]&&
   Hom_H(P_{n+1},C) \arrow[dd]\\
   &&
   Hom_G(P_n,A') \arrow[rr,"\alpha'",near start] \arrow[dr,dashed,swap,"d_n "] && Hom_G(P_n,B') \arrow[dr,dashed,swap,"d_n "]\arrow[rr,"\beta'",very near start]&& Hom_G(P_n,C')\arrow[dr,dashed,swap,"d_n "]\arrow[rr]&&0 \\
    &0\arrow[rr]&& Hom_G(P_{n+1},A') \arrow[rr,"\alpha'"]&& Hom_G(P_{n+1},B')\arrow[rr,"\beta'"]&& Hom_G(P_{n+1},C')
    \end{tikzcd}```
````

Comment: Please make your code compilable by adding the documentclass as well as the relevant packages. How to make sure your diagram fits into the textwidth depends on how much space is available.

Comment: Did you already try using a negative value for `column sep` such as `column sep = -10pt`?

Comment: @leandriis thanks negative value worked

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use *negative* column separation. For the narrow columns with just zeros, you can fix it with an explicit additional spacing doing `&[1em]`.

I suggest not to do `swap` for the diagonal arrows and to employ `crossing over` (which requires to postpone the drawing of some arrows).

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath,tikz-cd}

\DeclareMathOperator{\Hom}{Hom}

\begin{document}

\[
\begin{tikzcd}[row sep=1.5em, column sep = -2em]
&&[1em]
\Hom_H(P_n,A) \arrow[rr,"\alpha"] \arrow[dr,dashed, "d_n"] \arrow[dd,swap] &&
\Hom_H(P_n,B) \arrow[dd] \arrow[dr,dashed,"d_n"] \arrow[rr,"\beta"]&&
\Hom_H(P_n,C) \arrow[rr]\arrow[dr,dashed ,"d_n "] \arrow[dd] &&[1em]
0
\\
&
0\arrow[rr,crossing over] &&
\Hom_H(P_{n+1},A) \arrow[rr,"\alpha",near start,crossing over] &&
\Hom_H(P_{n+1},B) \arrow[rr,"\beta",near start,crossing over] &&
\Hom_H(P_{n+1},C) 
\\
&&
\Hom_G(P_n,A') \arrow[rr,"\alpha'",near start] \arrow[dr,dashed,"d_n "] &&
\Hom_G(P_n,B') \arrow[dr,dashed,"d_n "] \arrow[rr,"\beta'",very near start] &&
\Hom_G(P_n,C') \arrow[dr,dashed,"d_n "] \arrow[rr] &&
0
\\
&
0\arrow[rr] &&
\Hom_G(P_{n+1},A') \arrow[rr,"\alpha'"] \arrow[from=uu,crossing over] &&
\Hom_G(P_{n+1},B') \arrow[rr,"\beta'"] \arrow[from=uu,crossing over] &&
\Hom_G(P_{n+1},C') \arrow[from=uu,crossing over]
\end{tikzcd}
\]

\end{document}
```

[image]

This makes an overfull box of about 7pt in the standard text width for `article`. I could slightly change the column separation in order to fit, but this requires knowing the text width you're using.

Note that “Hom” should be upright as shown in the picture.

Comment: It seems negative values works. Thanks for your help. Also I don't know about crossing over too. Your diagram looks much better

Answer (score 2):

For fun, the same diagram made with `pstricks`:

```
\documentclass[border=10pt]{standalone}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\DeclareMathOperator{\Hom}{Hom} 
\usepackage{pst-node}

\begin{document}

$ \begin{psmatrix}[colsep=0.4cm, rowsep=0.8cm]
        & \Hom_H(P_n,A) & & \Hom_H(P_n,B) & & \Hom_H(P_n,C) & & 0\\
        0 & & \Hom_H(P_{n+1},A) & & \Hom_H(P_{n+1},B) & & \Hom_H(P_{n+1},C) \\
        & \Hom_G(P_n,A) & & \Hom_G(P_n,B) & & \Hom_G(P_n,C) & & 0\\
        0 & & \Hom_G(P_{n+1},A) & & \Hom_G(P_{n+1},B) & & \Hom_G(P_{n+1},C)
        %% arrows
        \psset{linewidth=0.5pt, arrowsize=4pt, arrows=->, linejoin=1, nodesep=4pt, labelsep=2pt}
        %% vertical arrows
        \foreach \i in{2,4,6}{\ncline{1,\i}{3,\i}}
        %% horizontal arrows
        \foreach \i/\j/\k/\label in {1/2/4/\alpha, 1/4/6/\beta, 2/3/5/\alpha, 2/5/7/\beta}
        {\ncline[border=3pt]{\i,\j}{\i,\k}\naput[npos=0.43]{\label}}
        \foreach \i/\j/\k/\label in {3/2/4/\alpha', 3/4/6/\beta', 4/3/5/\alpha', 4/5/7/\beta'} {\ncline{\i,\j}{\i,\k}\naput[npos=0.43]{\label}}
        \ncline[border=3pt]{2,1}{2,3}\ncline[border=3pt]{4,1}{4,3}
        \ncline{1,6}{1,8}\ncline[border=3pt]{3,6}{3,8}
        %% foreground vertical arrows
        \foreach \i in{3,5,7}{\ncline[border=3pt]{2,\i}{4,\i}}
        %% \dashed arrows
        \foreach \i/\j in {2/3,4/5,6/7}{\psset{npos=0.3, linestyle=dashed, dash=3pt 2pt, labelsep=1pt}%
         \ncline{1,\i}{2,\j}\nbput{d_n}\ncline{3,\i}{4,\j}\nbput{d_n}}
    \end{psmatrix} $

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: @SandyG: I agree. I simply reproduced the image posted by the O.P., but it suffices to remove the  `[border=3pt]` for the second `\ncline` – and in my opinion, to add it to the corresponding vertical lines,which implies changing the order of some commands.

Comment: @SandyG: Does this new version befit you?

Comment: @Bernard thanks. I don't know about psmatrix. I will check it out. Also thanks for letting me know there is a option of crossing over. It looks much cleaner now

Comment: @Bernard: Yes! But more importantly, It seems OP likes it better.